# Memory footprint for Redis empty instance

Tags: redis

I've been investigating about the memory footprint usage of a Redis empty instance (because I'm interested by enabling Redis as cache provider in a low-ram device).

The documentation says that the memory footprint should be ~3MB (previous versions were only 1MB but I suppose that new features should have been increased this size).

I've tested Redis 4.0.0 (just released!) using Docker three official containers (https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/): Debian with Redis 32 and 64 bits, and Alpine (Redis 64 bits).

The results are:

Debian with Redis 32 bits:

- gcc_version:4.9.2
- used_memory_rss_human:3.40M

Debian with Redis 64 bits:

- gcc_version:4.9.2
- used_memory_rss_human:3.84M

Alpine Redis 64 bits:

- gcc_version:6.3.0
- used_memory_rss_human:2.11M

The documentation states that 32 bit instances have lower consumption of memory . It is consistent with the difference between 32bit and 64bit debian instances but not with the alpine version.

Is the gcc version the responsible to have lower footprint in the alpine instance than the debian instance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, the difference probably comes from the runtime libraries (ie. glibc or musl). It makes a bigger difference than 32 bits vs 64 bits when the instance is empty (but probably not when you have some data).